# Avoid overlapping between HTML elements that with absolute position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a Product List with each single product defined as div with absolute position (Like the pinterest pins page). Unfortunately all the products are overlapping each other.

Note: I am adding the product using a WordPress theme, so I cannot add Left and Top position for each div

Comment: Please share your html and css code.

Comment: Can you show us your html/css/relevant code?  This is how absolute positioning is *supposed* to work .. maybe you want to absolutely position the container.

Comment: z-index? show your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using position absolute, then pretty much adding top and left would be the solution. Is there a way you could add the top-left coordinates via Javascript? Calculating the width + a little margin.

In any case, why would you set absolute the position? Any chance you could change it to relative or static?

Comment: Below is the used css:

    .default_product_display {
    position: absolute;
    border-color: #7F7F7F;
    border-style: dotted;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: 225px;
    margin-left: 36.1px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-right: 0;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px lightgray;
    }

I cannot use relative position, as each div has different width, and I don't want some div affect the entire row below it

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by using jQuery Masonry function, I was not aware that it's already in WordPress